# How to print the whole response on the console

Tags: java, sockets

I can't print the whole response from the server on the console!
,
There are 3 ways to bypass this matter,

1. Add this header **Connection: close**
2. Replace **HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/1.0**
3. Add this `s.close(); // Socket.close();`

I can't close the connection because I want to send more than once at the same connection,

I just want to print the whole response without closing the connection.

```
String content = "GET /Zuck HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.facebook.com\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing your code returns the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.facebook.com/zuck
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
X-FB-Debug: NHDnNLmTeg5PBPiSL7++1dz/ZdRbnlnKy1gpdfBbLFkvrhbJMJT+nLJd1VYpmEkkkUtmvXsjgLvFEeML/82WUA==
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 15:36:24 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

HTTP reponse status code [302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) indicates a redirect to the Location: *https://www.facebook.com/zuck*. Either handle redirects in your code or - to get your example running - simply replace *Zuck* with *zuck* in your content string.

Comment: You're a great programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your operating on raw socket you actually cannot determine when you have received whole response. You can however do it with protocols like http in same cases.

In your example you receive `Content-Length: 0` which tells the number (0) of bytes the body of message have.

You can also pass header `Connection: close` which closes connection after sending full response, but I think it is not what you're looking for.

You can also just do read/write operations on two separate threads.